# Can php have a mixed type hinting?

Tags: php, type-hinting

Say my function want to accept both string and integer. And if it is string, I convert it to int afterwards.

Like

```
function func(int|string $a) {
    echo is_string($a)?intval($a)+1:$a+1;
}

func(1344);
func('1344');
```

Comment: try `function func($a) {
  return (intval($a)+1);
}` php don't really care to know what datatype you send him as arguments.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier. That is not what I want. I just want to extends the type hinting ability to restrict the type to 2 types, except for 1.

Comment: As is, PHP doesn't provide this feature. Either way, you'd have to create your own function. Otherwise simply modify your PHP to handle the data as it comes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The feature you asked for is in the proposal phase. See [PHP RFC: Union Types](https://web.archive.org/web/20170416233057/https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types).

**Update**

`Mixed` type has been ultimately accepted and introduced in [PHP 8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php) released in November 2020.

Comment: Seems there is new proposal https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mixed-typehint, and that one has status "Under Discussion"

Comment: Still not implemented as of PHP 7.4.4, thou currently `In Draft` and proposed for a `7.4.x` release.

Comment: It will be in PHP 8.0  https://php.watch/versions/8.0#mixed-type  scheduled for release on Dec 3, 2020.

Answer (score 4):

Mixed was accepted for PHP 8.0: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mixed_type_v2

```
class B
{
    public function foo(mixed $value) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Union types [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2) has been accepted and implemented for PHP 8.

Mixed type [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mixed_type_v2) is being voted on, but likely to pass at time of writing this answer.